# Thingsboard issue: How Can I get the currently logged in user in my custom widget

Tags: javascript, thingsboard

I created my own custom widget. But the problem is I can't access the currently logged in user in my widget. I searched for many times but found only 1 solution.

```js
var $injector = self.ctx.$scope.$injector;
var userService = $injector.get('userService');
var userId = userService.getCurrentUser().userId;
```

But this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: When you use this code, are you getting datas from database ?

Comment: It's an API to get current user data. I solved it.

Comment: How did you solve? Can you share your code as answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`userService` will not work after TB3.0

So you may try this:

```js
var user = self.ctx.currentUser;  
console.log(user);
```

It works well for me.